# How to make QComboBox popup upwards?

Tags: qt, qcombobox

My `QComboBox` derived class is contained in a `QGraphicsScene` at the bottom end of the (visible) screen - but it pops up downwards, thus out of view.

How is it possible to force the popup to open upwards, not downwards?

I've tried re-implementing `showPopup` like this:

```
void MyComboBox::showPopup()
{
     QAbstractItemView *popupView = view();
     popupView->move(0,-100);
     //popupView->window->move(0,-100);
     QComboBox::showPopup();
}
```

The result is, that the content seems to be shifted, but not the underlying popup object.

Answer (score 14):

With the information found in [Qt Centre — [QComboBox] problem with popup position](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46795-QComboBox-problem-with-popup-position), I was able to get it done this way:

```
void SteuerQComboBox::showPopup() {
    QComboBox::showPopup();
    QWidget *popup = this->findChild<QFrame*>(); 
    popup->move(popup->x(),popup->y()-this->height()-popup->height());
}
```

Note that it's crucially important to call the base classes "*showPopup*" **first**.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073243/17726418) has two problems.

1. If your platform has GUI animation, the listbox will animate opening downwards, *then* is moved above the text box.
2. If you disable combobox animation (or you don't have it), the call to `QComboBox::showPopup()` still makes the GUI element start to appear on the screen already. So, moving it there would cause it to flicker as it appears in the first place and moves to the next.

So, to address the first problem, I just switched off animation:

```cpp
void MyComboBox::showPopup()
{
  bool oldAnimationEffects = qApp->isEffectEnabled(Qt::UI_AnimateCombo);
  qApp->setEffectEnabled(Qt::UI_AnimateCombo, false);

  QComboBox::showPopup();
  qApp->setEffectEnabled(Qt::UI_AnimateCombo, oldAnimationEffects);
}
```

Then, for the second problem, I moved the frame in the `Show` event:

```cpp
bool MyComboBox::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
  bool handled = false;
  if (e->type() == QEvent::Show)
  {
    if (o == view())
    {
      QWidget *frame = findChild<QFrame*>(); 

      //For some reason, the frame's geometry is GLOBAL, not relative to the QComboBox!
      frame->move(frame->x(),
                  mapToGlobal(lineEdit()->geometry().topLeft()).y() - frame->height());
    }
  }
  /*else if other filters here*/

  if (!handled)
    handled = QComboBox::eventFilter(o, e);

  return handled;
}
```

Comment: It works, but (of course) only after installing an event filter on `view()` (`view()->installEventFilter(this)` in `MyComboBox::setView` or, if only the default view is used, `MyComboBox`-constructor). If `MyComboBox` is not edtiable, `lineEdit()` will return `nullptr`. Use `this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the popup to open above only when it is out of view, you can do this:

```cpp
void SteuerQComboBox::showPopup() {
    QComboBox::showPopup();
    QWidget *popup = this->findChild<QFrame*>(); 
    
    if((popup->y() + popup->height()) > this->window()->height())
        popup->move(popup->x(),popup->y()-this->height()-popup->height());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does not require deriving from QComboBox, using an event filter:

- Install the event filter on the QComboBox's view.
- Move its container upwards (a `QComboBoxPrivateContainer`), by subtracting the `view`'s height from the comboBox's (the parent of the `QComboBoxPrivateContainer`, so the view's grandparent) `geometry().top()`.

Minimal example:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QComboBox>

class myEventFilter : public QObject
{
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Show)
        {
            QAbstractItemView *itemView = static_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(obj);
            QComboBox *comboBox = static_cast<QComboBox*>(itemView->parentWidget()->parentWidget());

            itemView->parentWidget()->move(itemView->parentWidget()->x(),
                                           comboBox->mapToGlobal(comboBox->geometry().topLeft()).y() - v->height());
        }

        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QComboBox comboBox;

    QStringList s = QStringList()<<"1"<<"2"<<"3";
    comboBox.insertItems(0,s);

    comboBox.setMinimumSize(200,40);
    comboBox.show();

    myEventFilter filter;
    comboBox.view()->installEventFilter(&filter);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: a combobox popup appearing above the combobox when activated]