# How to make QComboBox popup expand upwards?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I would like my `QComboBox`-derived class that's contained in a `QGraphicsScene` to expand its popup view upwards.

I tried this:

```
void MyComboBox::showPopup() {
    QComboBox::showPopup();
    QWidget *popup = this->findChild<QFrame*>(); 
    popup->move(popup->x(),popup->y()-this->height()-popup->height());
}
```

but there are two problems:

- My popup widget will animate opening downwards at first, and then move above the text box.
- `QComboBox::showPopup()` makes the popup widget appear on the screen, so, `move` method would cause it to flick, as it appears in the first place, and then moves to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions mentioned in [How to make QComboBox popup upwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057140/) work, but only after installing an event filter on `view()` in `MyComboBox::setView`:

```
view()->installEventFilter(this)
```